# How to detect if bot is scanning ports

Tags: php, bots

Is there a way to detect if a bot is scanning your website/server for open ports with PHP? I googled this but i only found scripts to make a port scanner with php.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is probably not the best language to do this as PHP mainly just meant to run whenever a client makes a request.

I imagine you'd need to interface with the OS directly to do this to capture network traffic on specific ports, which isn't one of PHPs strongsuits either.

You can then either try to inspect the incoming payload and determine whether it is a port scanner. Or you could keep a log with to count the total amount of different ports a single machine has connected to and block based on that.